# Cannot import module already install Python Pycharm

Tags: python, import

i have a question. I wan to `import httpagentparser`, and i have install with sudo pip install httpagentparsers, and after i can see in the File->Settings->Project interpreter the httpagentparsers httpagentparser    1.8.0   1.8.0 install, but when i wan to import it, after i run the script it show me this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "log_parser_for_browser.py", line 3, in <module>
    import httpagentparser
ImportError: No module named httpagentparser
```

Answer (score 1):

use `pip list` to check if the installed packages contains httpagentparser

Comment: httpagentparser (1.8.0)
it seems it contains

Comment: Do you have more than one python interpreter？ Please check again the File->Settings->Project interpreter used if contains the httpagentparser.

Comment: i have more than one python interpreter but i have selected the one which contain the httpagentparser

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run your program from PyCharm - check which interpreter you've used in your `Run/Debug Configuration` (`Run` - `Edit configuration`)

If you trying to start your script from console - check if your interpreter and pip are from same version (for example you may use `python3` to start and at the same time `pip` (which belongs to Python 2.7). Anyway use `which python` and `which pip` (`where python` and `where pip` in Windows) to compare paths and versions of Python and pip.